# Add title for previous and next posts to Yoko Theme

Tags: posts, title, next, previous

Help! I want to change my "Previous" and "Next" post links to use the actual post titles. I have done all kinds of online research and code manipulation without any success.

I am using the Yoko theme. Here is my current single.php code. What do I need to update it to be? My website is www.thelawstudentswife.com

```
<div id="content">

<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'single' ); ?>

        <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>

        <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

        <nav id="nav-below">
            <div class="nav-previous"><?php previous_post_link( '%link', '' . _x( '&larr;  Previous Post', 'Previous post link', 'yoko' ) . '' ); ?></div>
            <div class="nav-next"><?php next_post_link( '%link', __('') . _x( 'Next Post &rarr;', 'Next post link', 'yoko' ) . '' ); ?></div>
        </nav><!-- end nav-below -->

</div><!-- end content -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, nice and simple:

```
<?php next_post('%', 'Prev: ', 'yes'); ?>
<?php previous_post('%', 'Next: ', 'yes'); ?>
```

Comment: These functions are deprecated and may stop to work eventually.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work. Instead, it removed the "previous" and "next" links all together. Can you explain specifically what text I should copy over? Maybe that is my problem. Or can you paste what the entire code should look like?

Answer (score 1):

straight from the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_post_link);

example:

```
<div class="nav-previous"><?php previous_post_link( '%link', '&larr; %title' ); ?></div>
<div class="nav-next"><?php next_post_link( '%link', '%title  &rarr;' ); ?></div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work. Instead, it removed the "previous" and "next" links all together. Can you explain specifically what text I should copy over? Maybe that is my problem. Or can you paste what the entire code should look like? Also, I think the word 'yoko' needs to stay in there somewhere....

Comment: these edited lines replace the identical divs in your code; the 'yoko' bit is for translation purposes only.

Answer (score 1):

Easily enough:

```
    <nav id="nav-below">
        <div class="nav-previous"><?php previous_post_link(); ?></div>
        <div class="nav-next"><?php next_post_link(); ?></div>
    </nav><!-- end nav-below -->
```

The `previous_post_link()` and `next_post_link` functions return a link which text is the title of the post.